# how to change date format to isostring

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, dynamic-arrays

I have array of object and I would like to change date format for both date.[date and dateofbirth]into iso string. I tried to use map to change date format but with no luck.
how can i change date format for both dates dynamically?

```
//array of object
const emp = [
{ name: "John", age: 22, date: "2015-03-25", dateofbirth: "1990-03-25" },
{ name: "Peter", age: 20, date: "2015-04-23", dateofbirth: "1389-03-03" },
{ name: "Mark", age: 23, date: "2015-01-20", dateofbirth: "1970-11-03" }
];

//my code 
let modifiedArr = emp.map(function (newDate) {
return newDate.date.toISOString;
});

console.log(modifiedArr);
```

Comment: `newDate.date` is a string, and if you mean the `toISOString()` method of `Date`, the `()` is important too. Try `return new Date(newDate.date).toISOString();` instead, though I'm not sure if that output is really what you want.

Comment: it works as I wanted but I want to change all date in my array.

Comment: "2015-03-25" **is** ISO 8601 format. If you want the time also, then just append "T00:00:00Z", no need for parsing and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Please read up on and get better understanding of the `map()` function from  [the documentation of `map()` function in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

The `map()` function iterates over the array and applies the specified callback on each item.

Next, you need to construct `Date` objects using the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Only then can you call the `toISOString()` method.

```js
//array of object
const emp = [
  { name: "John", age: 22, date: "2015-03-25", dateofbirth: "1990-03-25" },
  { name: "Peter", age: 20, date: "2015-04-23", dateofbirth: "1389-03-03" },
  { name: "Mark", age: 23, date: "2015-01-20", dateofbirth: "1970-11-03" },
];

//my code
let modifiedArr = emp.map(function (empRecord) {
  return {
    ...empRecord,
    date: new Date(empRecord.date).toISOString(),
    dateofbirth: new Date(empRecord.dateofbirth).toISOString(),
  };
});

console.log(modifiedArr);
```

However, I strongly recommend [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) whenever dealing with dates. Simply because the vanilla JS Date API is borked.

Comment: Why not simply `date: empRecord.date + 'T00:00:00Z'`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const emp = [
    {name: "John", age: 22, date: "2015-03-25", dateofbirth: "1990-03-25"},
    {name: "Peter", age: 20, date: "2015-04-23", dateofbirth: "1389-03-03"},
    {name: "Mark", age: 23, date: "2015-01-20", dateofbirth: "1970-11-03"}
];
let dateKeys = ['date', 'dateofbirth'];
var getDateInISO = function(date) {
    return new Date(date).toISOString();
}
let modifiedArr = emp.map(function (elem) {
    dateKeys.forEach(function(date) {
        elem[date] = getDateInISO(elem[date]);
    })
    return elem;
});
console.log(modifiedArr);
```

Comment: @Sakill perfect but how can i do it if I have several date in my array and each time the name is different ?

Comment: @admin create array of keys to convert, create function which will take the string and give you date in ISO format, loop through the array and change the values

Comment: @admin, code is updated

Answer (score 0):

**toISOString()** is method inside the javascript **Date** class, While the value of the date attribute is a string literal. Hence you will first have to get an instance of the Date class and then invoke the toISOString() function.

This can be done in the following way,

```
let modifiedArr = emp.map(function (item) {

  // This will create a Date object representing the given date
  const currDate = new Date(item.date);

  return currDate.toISOString;
});
```